# AngularJs : datatable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datatables

I need to use Angularjs datatable for my project for the features like search and sorting etc. 
My current structure is :-

**HTML**

```
<table datatable="" class="table table-striped table-bordered row-border hover" ng-show=query_executed>
    <thead >
        <tr >
            <th ng-repeat="x in keys">{{x}}</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="ScrollStyle">
            <tr ng-repeat="y in myWelcome">
                <td ng-repeat="z in y">{{z}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Here keys contain column names.
y is rows and z is elements of rows.

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.GetQueryResult = function() {
    $http.get('view2/datafile.html')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.myWelcome = data[1]["result_text"]["data"][0]["chunk_data"];
            $rootScope.colname = $rootScope.myWelcome[0];
            var key, x;
            $rootScope.keys = [];

            for (key in $rootScope.colname) {
                if ($rootScope.colname.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    ($rootScope.keys).push(key);
            }



        })
        .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
            $rootScope.myWelcome = status;

        });
};
```

But the problem is i am not getting required features described above.

**Current page:-**
[view of my current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEAXI.png)

I would like to know the problem with the code.

Thanks.

Comment: using ng-repeat has performance issues for big data, and you have 3 maybe the approach needs to change? just a pointer

Comment: @Harry Thanks for the suggestion, but i was using ng-repeat to fill the table.

Comment: u can use ng-repeat but you are using more than 1 each ng-repeat will create items with its own scope and will slow it down